# IText 7, Create Table in Every Page

Tags: c#, line, itext7

I try to create line on every page:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
     SolidLine line = new SolidLine(1f);
    //line.SetColor(Color.RED);
    LineSeparator ls = new LineSeparator(line).SetFixedPosition(100, 100, 50f);
}
```

Unfortunately it shows up only in the last page. How to do it? thanks

Comment: I don't see your code adding anything to any page.

Comment: Ok ,tahnks Sir, I have change the line using:  p.Add(new Text("________________________________________________________________"));

Comment: I'm afraid I still cannot see how you add your `ls` to any page.